# R data.table - different join behavior for integer/numeric and character columns

Tags: r, data.table

I have two data.tables `DT` and `ADT` and I want to join them on columns `a, new.a`:

```
R> DT
   a   b
1: 1 1.0
2: 1 1.0
3: 2 2.0
4: 3 3.5
5: 4 4.5
6: 5 5.5

R> ADT
   new.a type
1:     1    3
2:     1    5
3:     2    3
4:     4    5
5:     4    3

R> setkey(DT, a)
R> DT[ADT[, new.a]]
# This is the desired result:
   a   b
1: 1 1.0
2: 1 1.0
3: 1 1.0
4: 1 1.0
5: 2 2.0
6: 4 4.5
7: 4 4.5
```

Instead of the desired result, data.table takes the numeric information from `ADT[, new.a]` as a set of row numbers.

```
DT[ADT[, new.a]] # taking row numbers... even truncating comma-values!
setkey(DT, a)
DT[ADT[, new.a]] # the key sorts the DT, so slightly different result, still using row numbers
```

If instead, I define the data.tables differently, now containing `character` columns, I correctly get an error if I try the join before setting a key, and afterwards I get the desired result. But is there a way using the numeric indices directly? Converting the whole DT to characters upfront can get slow...

```
DTchar <- data.table(
  a = as.character(c(1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 5)),
  b = c(1, 2, 1, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5)
)
ADTchar <- data.table(
  new.a = as.character(c(1, 1, 2, 4, 4)),
  type  = as.character(c(3, 5, 3, 5, 3))
)

DTchar[ADTchar[, new.a]] # error - correctly
setkey(DTchar, a)
DTchar[ADTchar[, new.a]] # desired result
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, instead of `ADT[, new.a]`, which returns a vector, you should use `ADT[, list(new.a)]`, which returns a `data.table`.
You are also missing the argument `allow.cartesian = TRUE`.

```
DT[ADT[, list(new.a)], allow.cartesian = TRUE]
##    a   b
## 1: 1 1.0
## 2: 1 1.0
## 3: 1 1.0
## 4: 1 1.0
## 5: 2 2.0
## 6: 4 4.5
## 7: 4 4.5
```

From the documentation of `i` in `data.table`:

> integer and logical vectors work the same way they do in [.data.frame.
>
> character is matched to the first column of x's key.
>
> When i is a data.table, x must have a key. i is joined to x using x's key and the rows in x that match are returned.

Comment: Ah, I see. But then, a vector of characters is interpreted differently than a vector of numbers in data.table?

Comment: Yes, the only possible interpretation of a character vector is that it is supposed to be a `data.table` join. The most likely interpretation for an integer vector is that you want to consider them as indicees. See the documentation of `i` in `?data.table`.

Comment: Then I think, this was my major misunderstanding. So, any way of packing numeric vectors into a "query-data.table" will work around this, I guess?

Comment: read **carefully**, not just scroll through is the lesson I learned